# Adsense Ads Not Showing Up

Tags: google-adsense

My Adsense Ads aren't showing up. I have embedded the HTML into my website and placed it accordingly, but nothing shows up on the page.

It has been like this for two days now. Would this have something to do with my website creator?

Answer (score 4):

Is it white space or PSAs? What "website creator" did you use?

Ask yourself these questions (possible reasons):

1. Is there any reason your AdSense account may be under review or banned?
2. Did you copy or paste the AdSense code correctly?
3. Can you even view Google ads? Do you have JavaScript enabled? Do you have some sort of ad blocker enabled?
4. You are allowed a max of three AdSense ads units per page, might you have more?
5. Is your website suitable for AdSense ads? I had an article on Nude Beaches that would not show Google ads because the word "nude" is not allowed.

You may want to see if Google can see content on your site. Add Google webmaster tools to your site to see if there are any crawl errors.
[How your site looks to Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=google+bot+site+view):